# Trouble with emmeans in Rrstudio using GLM

Tags: r, glm, emmeans

I am trying to deploy the correct post-hoc test on my quasibinominal GLM but with no luck. I want to investigate the impact from each 6 responses of vegResponse , however, I am not too sure how to! When I use emmeans this doesn't separate the veg responses into each of it's 6 responses and instead just gives me one number. Could I have some help please:)

Here is my code and the picture has my results:

```
Modelboth  <- glm( counter_prop ~ appear_selected * label_selected * vegResponse, data=subset( aggDataOut ), family = quasibinomial(link='logit')  )

Modelboth.emm <- emmeans(Modelboth,  "vegResponse", type = "response")
Modelboth.emm

summary( Modelboth )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you have `vegResponse` coded as a numeric predictor (perhaps with values of 1, 2, ..., 6. In that case, `emmeans` would give you the mean prediction at the average of `vegResponse` = 3.5.

If I am correct, your model is almost surely incorrect too because it is fitting a linear trend for `vegResponse`, whereas you want to treat those as six distinct levels of a factor. So you should re-fit the model with `vegResponse` replaced by `factor(vegResponse)`.

But also note that there appear to be strong interactions in your model, in which case it is *inappropriate* to summarize based on marginal means. You should likely use both of those other predictors as `by` variables, or at least one. I also strongly suggest visualizing the predictions, e.g. using something like

```
emmip(Modelboth, vegResponse ~ appear_selected | label_selected, type = "response")
```

Comment: Hey Russ, thanks for your very useful answer! I am confused as to what by variables means and how to create them? I created the model again but with the factor(vegResponse) and it works a treat, although in the model I am missing vegresponse 1?  Thanks again.

Comment: The `by` argument in `emmeans`